# Is there a function to display an image in tkinter (that is any file type) and display it as a specific x-y position on the canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have an array of image paths and a function that finds the paths connected to buttons that are where I want to display the image

I have already tried adding

```py
    file_path = photo.name
    img = Image.open(file_path)
    photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    tk.Label(window, image=photo_image).pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

to my function but the photos end up being too big and I want the pictures to be placed right above the buttons so I know the exact x-y coordinates I want the pictures to be I just need a way to get them there and to make them smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resize your image, pass a tuple of size in pixels:

```
img = Image.open("1.bmp").resize((640, 480))
```

To place your image right above the buttons, you can use place.

```
tk.Label(root, image=photo_image).place(x=0,y=0) #change x and y to your desired value
```

You can also get the current loc of your button widget to calculate the exact location on where you need to `place` your label:

```
x,y = widget.winfo_x(), widget.winfo_y()
```

To sum it up:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def place_image():
    x, y = button1.winfo_x(), button1.winfo_y()
    tk.Label(root, image=photo_image).place(x=x,y=y+20)

button1 = tk.Button(root,text="Click me",command=place_image)
button1.pack()
img = Image.open("1.bmp").resize((400, 300))
photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the label at specific pixel coordinates within the canvas using .place(). You can also define the label's width and height in pixels, inside the brackets. This will therefore define the width and height in pixels, of the image.

E.g:

```
tk.Label(window, image=photo_image).place(x=300, y=400, width=200, height=50)
```

place() Pixel coordinates work like this in tkinter (for a 600 pixel by 600 pixel canvas):

[image: diagrma]

Increasing a tkinter widget's X coordinate moves it rightwards. 
Increasing a tkinter widget's Y coordinate moves it downwards.